# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find property named "consumed" on mapped class Instances->instance in this Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this query

```py
self.session.query(Instances).options(joinedload('consumed')).outerjoin(Consumed).filter(
    and_(
        queryInstances.customer_id == customer_id,
        queryInstances.purged == 'false'
    )
)
```

that returns the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find property named "consumed" on mapped class Instances->instance in this Query.

And my classes are
Instances:

```py
class Instances(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'instance'
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, server_default=FetchedValue())
    coupon_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey(Coupon.id), nullable=False)
    customer_id = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=FetchedValue())
    reference = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    offline_data = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    purged = Column(BOOLEAN, nullable=False)
    customer_info = Column(JSONB)
    locked_for = Column(TEXT)
    locked_until = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    expires_at = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    coupon = relationship(Coupon, lazy='joined')
```

and Consumed:

```py
class Consumed(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'consumed'
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, server_default=FetchedValue())
    instance_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey(Instances.id), nullable=False)
    consumed_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=FetchedValue())
    pos_id = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    instance = relationship(Instances, backref=backref('consumed', uselist=False), lazy='joined')
```

Why I'm getting this error?
SQLAlchemy version 1.4

Comment: What is `queryInstances` in your example query ?  Should that just be `Instances`?

Comment: I tried to setup a similar example and could not get the same error to occur using postgresql + sqlalchemy (1.4.28).